# GTM Custom JavaScript with RegEx to define GA4-Measurement ID

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

what I'm trying to do is to if-else the measurement id based on the host name to separate stage and prod - properties  I can't use the host name as it is because it will be implemented on various domains.

Here is what seemingly doesn't work:

```
function Host Name(a){
    let measurementID;
    if (a = '.*stage.*|.*test.*' ){
        measurementID = 'G-123456';
    } else { measurementID = 'G-abcdefg'}
    return measurementID
}
```

Is this the right way at all? Could you help correct the js?

Thx

Comment: Please, provide an example of the staging and production `URLs`

Comment: mycustomerA.test.mywebdeveloper.com  and myapp.mycustomerA.com

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know how to use regular expression to compare the string you want ?

Here is the document from

**RegExp.prototype.test()**

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Sameple from the document

```js
const str = 'table football';

const regex = new RegExp('foo*');

console.log(regex.test(str));
// expected output: true
```